# Excel Add In Worksheet.SelectionChange Does Not Fire After Deployment

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

My Excel Add In hooks into the SelectionChange event of two worksheets. The event fires, and is responded to appropriately, in my development environment. However, once it is deployed to a client machine, the event doesn't trigger. Dev and user environments are as close as I can get them (Windows, Office, etc. all same version).

I'll admit... I haven't done much to troubleshoot this because I'm at a loss.

Comment: most likely, somewhere in your code you used `Application.EnableEvents = False`- and you forgot to reset it back to True. At least that's what always happens to me... ;-)

Comment: I wish it were that simple. I haven't disabled events at all.

Comment: Which two worksheets (assuming they are sheets in a different XLS/XLSX/XLSM file)? Are these sheets referred to by name or index? Is it possible that the user's environment doesn't match your dev environment in this regard?

Comment: Does the rest of your add-in work correctly?

Comment: Everything else works perfectly. Reading from cells to create business objects, manipulating those business objects, then writing new values to the workbook.

Comment: Check other addins installe on client machine, as peter pointed out it could be Application.EnableEvents = False from any other addin there

Comment: Alternatively, if any routine (also other addins) use `END` - or the user presses the Stop button in the Debugger, your Objects that binds SelectionChange event will be reset to `Nothing`. Therefore, the events won't fire anymore either - or rather: the firing of the events is not captured anymore. Try testing for `objCatcher is Nothing` to see if this might be the cause...